# How to delete a row from table linked to another tables with primary and foreign keys with query in Laravel controller?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, laravel, vue.js

I have this this function below to retrieve data from database using the following query:

```
$matterConveyancing_all_tables = DB::table('matter_conveyancings')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_b_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_b_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_c_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_c_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_d_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_d_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_e_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_e_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->select('matter_conveyancings.*', 'matter_conveyancing_b_s.*', 'matter_conveyancing_c_s.*', 'matter_conveyancing_d_s.*', 'matter_conveyancing_e_s.*')
    ->get();
```

and getting everything correct

now i am trying to do the same way and query a delete to database with the code below

```
public function destroy(MatterConveyancing $matterConveyancing,$id)
{
    DB::table('matter_conveyancings')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_b_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_b_s.'.$id)
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_c_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_c_s.'.$id)
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_d_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_d_s.'.$id)
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_e_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_e_s.'.$id)
    ->delete();
    // $delete->delete();
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>"True!"
    ]);
}
```

i tried the above and got the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'matter_conveyancing_b_s.1' in 'on clause' (SQL: delete `matter_conveyancings` from `matter_conveyancings` inner join `matter_conveyancing_b_s` on `matter_conveyancings`.`id` = `matter_conveyancing_b_s`.`1` inner join `matter_conveyancing_c_s` on `matter_conveyancings`.`id` = `matter_conveyancing_c_s`.`1` inner join `matter_conveyancing_d_s` on `matter_conveyancings`.`id` = `matter_conveyancing_d_s`.`1` inner join `matter_conveyancing_e_s` on `matter_conveyancings`.`id` = `matter_conveyancing_e_s`.`1`)
```

i tried to return only the ID to check if its returning the correct id and it is returning the correct ID

so what seems to be the problem here?

---

"Extra code from the view"

```
deleteConveyancingMatter(id) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this Matter ?")) {
    this.axios
      .delete(`/api/auth/matter-conv/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.getConveyMatters();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
},
```

Button:

```
<a style="color: #7367f0" @click="deleteConveyancingMatter(conveymatter.id)"
                  ><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i
                ></a>
```

---

update:

i tried the following to add WHERE and managed to receive the message (Done!)
but no data has been deleted ..

```
public function destroy(MatterConveyancing $matterConveyancing,$id)
{
    DB::table('matter_conveyancings')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_b_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_b_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_c_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_c_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_d_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_d_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_e_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_e_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->where('matter_conveyancings.id',$id)
    ->delete('matter_conveyancings', 'matter_conveyancing_b_s', 'matter_conveyancing_c_s','matter_conveyancing_d_s','matter_conveyancing_e_s');
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Done!'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `'matter_conveyancing_b_s.'.$id` this is producing invalid SQL.

Comment: so what is the correct way to pass the id in my case?

Comment: use a `WHERE` clause https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_where.asp

Comment: i have updated my question by adding WHERE but still

Comment: Test your delete query by changing it to a select query (with the same where clause) to make sure your query is finding rows to delete.

Comment: i have mentioned in my question that i'm using the same query to get the data

Comment: would you mind move to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249855/discussion-between-sam-and-bassxzero).

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by user "bassxzero"

```
DB::table('matter_conveyancings')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_b_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_b_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_c_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_c_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_d_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_d_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->join('matter_conveyancing_e_s', 'matter_conveyancings.id', '=', 'matter_conveyancing_e_s.matter_conveyancings_id')
    ->where('matter_conveyancings.id',$id)
    ->delete();
```

Much appreciated bassxzero